# ItemService REST API - retrieve children of an item in batches

Tags: item-web-api

I'm wondering if there is a way to retrieve the item children in batches, I saw this ability other REST APIs where we can set pagination parameters like startIndex and itemPerPage.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the [Item Web API](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_restful_api_for_the_itemservice).

Basically you have 2 parameters

- *page*: Specify the page number in the result set of pages that the service shows.
- *pageSize*: Specify the number of results the service returns in the HTTP response.

Which will control how many items you get, and which virtual "page" to start from.

Example: `/item/{id}/query?pageSize&page&database&includeStandardTemplateFields&fields`

#### If you want to do it in native c# code

There is no such option. Basically when you hit `GetChildren()` or the `.Children` property of an `item` - all children will be resolved. This is also true for Item Web API querying, but you save a bit of bandwidth by only returning a subset.

Comment: Hey @mark-cassidy, to use the `/query` service, do we need extra configurations in the Sitecore side(or item)?  From the documentation `You use this method to run (“execute”) a query that is stored in a Sitecore item`, does that mean we need to set a query to each item?

Comment: That was just an example. If you follow the link, there are many types of queries you can be doing. It's basically a full REST API implementation, you can get items, delete items and so on.